# What this 'grandpa-voter' error means?

Tags: consensus, substrate-node-template, grandpa, private-network

I was doing last section of substrate private network tutorial.
Before i stored key set, i could started network smoothly.
But after i stored key set of aura and grandpa, i got this error.

```
yc6936@DESKTOP-P5M379O:~/substrate-node-template$ ./target/release/node-template --base-path /tmp/node01 --chain ./customSpecRaw.json --port 30333 --ws-port 9945 --rpc-port 9933 --telemetry-url "wss://telemetry.polkadot.io/submit/ 0" --validator --rpc-methods Unsafe --name MyNode01
2022-02-18 12:57:07 Low open file descriptor limit configured for the process. Current value: 4096, recommended value: 10000.
2022-02-18 12:57:07 Substrate Node
2022-02-18 12:57:07 ✌️  version 4.0.0-dev-b53da9f-x86_64-linux-gnu
2022-02-18 12:57:07 ❤️  by Substrate DevHub <https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub>, 2017-2022
2022-02-18 12:57:07  Chain specification: Custom Testnet
2022-02-18 12:57:07  Node name: MyNode01
2022-02-18 12:57:07  Role: AUTHORITY
2022-02-18 12:57:07  Database: RocksDb at /tmp/node01/chains/local_testnet/db/full
2022-02-18 12:57:07 ⛓  Native runtime: node-template-100 (node-template-1.tx1.au1)
2022-02-18 12:57:07 could not parse an IP from hosts file
2022-02-18 12:57:07 Using default protocol ID "sup" because none is configured in the chain specs
2022-02-18 12:57:07  Local node identity is: 12D3KooWPEhFE7KtZPrJu2qqFW5Lg71aYNYFTG36JmzTJrxL7JPm
2022-02-18 12:57:07 could not parse an IP from hosts file
2022-02-18 12:57:07  Highest known block at #0
2022-02-18 12:57:07 〽️ Prometheus exporter started at 127.0.0.1:9615
2022-02-18 12:57:07 Listening for new connections on 127.0.0.1:9945.
2022-02-18 12:57:08 GRANDPA voter error: Signing("Failed to sign GRANDPA vote for round 1 targetting 0x96b8d3a69d5dc2a2644964042185147b40b0159a7b8853bbcd12286096099fe4")
2022-02-18 12:57:08 Essential task `grandpa-voter` failed. Shutting down service.
Error: Service(Other("Essential task failed."))
```

What did i do wrong?

Comment: What does your plain chain spec file look like?

Comment: Does this command work fine: `./target/release/node-template --base-path /tmp/alice --chain local --alice --port 30333 --ws-port 9945 --rpc-port 9933 --node-key 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001 --telemetry-url "wss://telemetry.polkadot.io/submit/ 0" --validator`

Answer (score 2):

The key that you inserted into the keystore is probably invalid, the node fetches the key from the keystore in order to sign a GRANDPA vote and this fails. If you are generating keys for GRANDPA keep in mind that they need to be ed25519.

Unfortunately the error doesn't make it obvious what the problem is, we will add validation to keystore insertions in the future (so that you can't add an invalid key in the first place).

Comment: Hey @Andre, I was also facing the same error,
Even i have correct values to keystore path
https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/10189/cant-produce-new-blocks-with-custom-chainspec-file