# Cant produce new blocks with custom ChainSpec file

Tags: substrate-node-template, account, chainspec, finality, tutorials

I was using substrate version of `4.0.0-dev-41ad4a6c9d7` and following the [Add Trusted Nodes](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/build-a-blockchain/add-trusted-nodes/) for making a custom account as a Authorites account

here, I can't able to produce new blocks, I don't know what is the root cause,

I was running the nodes with only one local system, just using different terminals to run nodes

I have gone through a lot of stack exchange questions

[Can't able to peer two different node on different computers](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/9196/cant-able-to-peer-two-different-node-on-different-computers)

[Cannot produce and finalize blocks with 2 node peer](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/3414/cannot-produce-and-finalize-blocks-with-2-node-peer)

```
./target/release/node-template \
--base-path /tmp/node01 \
--chain ./devChainRaw.json \
--port 30333 \
--rpc-port 9933 \
--validator \
--rpc-cors all \
--rpc-external \
--rpc-methods Unsafe \
--name MyNode01

./target/release/node-template key insert --base-path /tmp/node01 \
  --chain ./devChainRaw.json \
  --scheme Sr25519 \
  --suri "risk charge consider cinnamon initial demise second mistake barely burger desert educate" \
  --key-type aura


./target/release/node-template key insert \
  --base-path /tmp/node01 \
  --chain ./devChainRaw.json \
  --scheme Ed25519 \
  --suri "risk charge consider cinnamon initial demise second mistake barely burger desert educate" \
  --key-type gran



./target/release/node-template \
  --base-path /tmp/node02 \
  --chain ./devChainRaw.json \
  --port 30334 \
  --rpc-port 9946 \
  --validator \
  --rpc-cors all \
  --rpc-external \
  --rpc-methods Unsafe \
  --name MyNode02 \
  --bootnodes /ip4/127.0.0.1/tcp/30333/p2p/12D3KooWBtsQ9sMwNAUYZv2iouoH5SnRmBLtf9SdpLL94LeHzDNM



./target/release/node-template key insert --base-path /tmp/node02 \
  --chain ./devChainRaw.json \
  --scheme Sr25519 \
  --suri "chef wise bunker slim shell drastic glory spike damp mystery tag butter" \
  --key-type aura



 ./target/release/node-template key insert --base-path /tmp/node02 \
  --chain ./devChainRaw.json \
  --scheme Ed25519 \
  --suri "chef wise bunker slim shell drastic glory spike damp mystery tag butter" \
  --key-type gran
```

plain chain specs file

```
{
  "name": "Development",
  "id": "dev",
  "chainType": "Development",
  "bootNodes": [],
  "telemetryEndpoints": null,
  "protocolId": null,
  "properties": null,
  "codeSubstitutes": {},
  "genesis": {
    "runtime": {
      "system": ''
    },
      "aura": {
        "authorities": [
          "5DcAu1NnYPqecdPYcuF9Q6seVzqn22iSdGZisyC5apE27CRu",
          "5FCK3YZoWddN3Q3DMC6KgXVsRNtVFkhbrX4NLcKWDnx2yG1s"
        ]
      },
      "grandpa": {
        "authorities": [
          [
            "5Cbh7iDuUoSqwiJmr3ya9PF2GAXaKSTuoFrX3EytVMkNMPrN",
            1
          ],
          [
            "5Dh4mZNHTmavtjhc2dfMoU5oe4HEPVZiZWEF3bPg6gBjrmnA",
            1
          ]
        ]
      },
      "balances": {
        "balances": [
          [
            "5DcAu1NnYPqecdPYcuF9Q6seVzqn22iSdGZisyC5apE27CRu",
            1152921504606846976
          ],
          [
            "5FCK3YZoWddN3Q3DMC6KgXVsRNtVFkhbrX4NLcKWDnx2yG1s",
            1152921504606846976
          ]
        ]
      },
      "transactionPayment": {
        "multiplier": "1000000000000000000"
      },
      "sudo": {
        "key": "5DcAu1NnYPqecdPYcuF9Q6seVzqn22iSdGZisyC5apE27CRu"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

I would like to why nodes haven't started producing blocks

Comment: Can you try again with the `--force-authoring` flag please?

Comment: hey @OliverTale-Yazdi ,

I was getting this error after restarting the node using --force-authoring

`2023-10-11 22:35:02 Running JSON-RPC server: addr=0.0.0.0:9933, allowed origins=["*"]    
2023-10-11 22:35:02 GRANDPA voter error: could not sign outgoing message: Failed to sign GRANDPA vote for round 1 targetting 0x4271ca3ade610e81e810075fac87a836306c97534f4517acd4688f8c70fecd23    
2023-10-11 22:35:02 Essential task ``grandpa-voter` failed. Shutting down service.    
Error: Service(Other("Essential task failed."))``